# Как правильно создать нейросеть на Python

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

И так есть набор данных в виде массива numpy получений с модуля sounddevice,
просто список float чисел состоящий из 1136 элементов (звук из микрофона) типа:

```
[[ 0.03588867]
 [ 0.03652954]
 [ 0.03622437]
 ...
 [-0.05761719]
 [-0.05273438]
 [-0.05368042]]
```

Как составить нейросеть что-бі она могла отличать один набор данных от другого какой модуль Python использовать .  Зарание спасибо.

Вот полный код которым этот массив получен::

```
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np
import pickle
duration = 180

data_dor = []

def callback(indata, outdata, frames, time, status):
    n  = np.linalg.norm(indata)*10
    if int(n) > 30:
        #data_dor.append( [s[0] for s in indata ] )
        #print("|" * int(n))
        print(indata)

with sd.Stream(channels=1, callback=callback):
    sd.sleep(int(duration * 1000))
```

Comment: Keras - пожалуй самая мощная штука для работы с нейросетями.

Comment: Переформулируйте вопрос. Что значит - "отличать один набор данных от другого". Потому что самый прямой ответ на ваш вопрос - это сравнить наборы поэлементно. Без всяких нейросетей.